# Unable to install erlang on cent os

Tags: erlang, centos, yum

While installing erlang on cent os I got the following error

> Error: Package: erlang-crypto-R16B03-0.2.el6.x86_64 (erlang-solutions)
>
> Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: erlang-crypto-R16B03-0.2.el6.x86_64 (erlang-solutions)
>
> Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I searched around on google and found that the probelm can be solved by installing openssl-devl. So I did that and tried installing erlang again but got the same error.

How can I install the latest version of erlang on cent os 6.4?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How you are installing it? According to Riak's documentation, you use:

```
sudo yum install gcc glibc-devel make ncurses-devel openssl-devel autoconf
```

And then, you build Erlang:

```
wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz
tar zxvf otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz
cd otp_src_R15B01
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

[Installing Erlang on GNU/Linux](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.3.0/tutorials/installation/Installing-Erlang/#Installing-on-GNU-Linux)

Comment: I was following the [official guide](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) but I will try out your method.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma Btw, ErlangSolutions isn't the original Erlang creator.

Comment: Done thanks :) I should have installed from the source in the first place

Answer (score 4):

You can install erlang using [erlang-solution](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/) repo

- Install repo

  `wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`

  `rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`
- Install erlang

  `sudo yum install erlang`

Comment: Failed Dependencies: epel-release is needed by erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on centos7...

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum update
wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install erlang
```

Comment: That packages.erlang-solutions.com link is broken at the moment, always returns a "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified" with no body. 
Via: 1.1 6d7d52006bd2b56c41485e39c5a03d58.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)

Comment: Also, rabbitmq now requires a more recent Erlang, see:
https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/fe34e83781f222dfd8533b36a52dddcc?permalink_comment_id=4667397#gistcomment-4667397

Answer (score 0):

your error is

> "Error: Package: erlang-crypto-***R16B03***-0.2.el6.x86_64"

so  you can download&install R16B03

```
wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B03.tar.gz

tar -zxvf src_R16B03.tar.gz

cd src_R16B03.tar.gz

yum localinstall erlang
```

Comment: A complete answer should be more than a simple link. Maybe some additional informations about how install the R16B03 package could be very appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Using EPEL from Fedora is a surefire way on Centos 6.  I currently have erlang-crypto-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64 installed.  If you have different repos enabled it could be a conflict or that there is an issue with the package from the other repo (I would recommend disabling whatever repo that provides it or at least ignoring erlang from that repo).

[Here is a simple way to install EPEL on Centos](https://realtechtalk.com/Centos_567_Install_EPEL_from_Fedora_for_extra_packages_Howto-1438-articles)

```
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
yum -y install erlang-*
```

Answer (score -1):

To install erlang in centos offline.Follow below steps,

1. We need to have one internet connected machine to download rpm's.

   ```
   yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly -y

   yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/user/ erlang
   ```

   All of erlang dependencies packages downloaded as rpm on `/home/user/` directory
2. Now copy all rpm's to offline machine in any directory ( eg., `/home/user/` )

   Type following command to install erlang with its dependencies too.,

   ```
   cd /home/user/

   rpm -Uvh *.rpm
   ```

It's Done!

check using command,

```
erl
```

(press <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> twice to get exit from `erl` command )